# Cannot deserialize a 'List<Object>' from BsonType 'Document'

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, webforms

I have declared a `List<object>` in a class for declaring property, and fetching data from mongodb using C#, ex:

```
public List<object> name {get;set;}
```

but it throws an error:

> "Cannot deserialize a 'List' from BsonType 'Document'"

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear, hope this answer can help you.
In Mongo DB, for every entry in a collection, there will be object id followed by fields. To import those data, you need to declare a class which is having same mongo DB fields,
like

```
// using MongoDB.Bson;
public class ToDo
    {
        public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
        public long ID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
    }
```

so final code to get all datat from datatbase like follows

```
           //  using MongoDB.Driver;
           //  using MongoDB.Bson;
             private static Object GetCollection()
              {
                IMongoClient  _client = new MongoClient();
                IMongoDatabase _database = _client.GetDatabase("<urDBname>");
                var _collection = _database.GetCollection<ToDo>("<urCOLLECTIONname>");
                var documents = _collection.Find(new BsonDocument()).ToListAsync().Result;
                return documents;
              }
```

here documents will give the list of documents present in database collections.
***Make sure that your Mongo server is running properly.***

Comment: Hello @mahender. This didn't work for me. Same error